# Flash is not available in chrome browser

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, flash, adobe

http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ - Flash is not available in chrome browser, even when the Update Manager mentions that the software is available. What should I do?

Comment: Chrome browser comes with its own built-in Flash player, so there is no need to install an additional Adobe Flash Player in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound pepperflashplugin-nonfree`

And close and re-open Chrome Browser.

Comment: Well, I hope this works for you.

Comment: What's the point of installing another Flash player in a web browser that already comes with its own built-in Flash player?

Comment: Sometimes I needed install it too, like in chromium. Maybe solves his problem. If Google Chrome says that Flash is not available, installing this packages could solve his problem.

Comment: Adobe Flash Player in Chromium web browser is *very* out of date (version 11). You can install exactly the same flash player that Google Chrome uses, currently version 15, in Chromium web browser by installing Pepper Flash Player - Browser plugin from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

You could install it by typing `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound`.